# How to update state by child's index on child list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a simple list of items like this:

```
const nodeList = Array.from({length:10}, (_,i) => i + 1)
const Counter = () => {
    
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)  
    return (
      <div>
       {nodeList.map((node,i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <button 
              onClick={() => {
                setCount(prev => prev + 1)
              }}
            >
              Sum up
            </button>
            <span>{count}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
        
      </div>
    )
  }
```

but when I click on sum up the count value is the same for all elements, how can I get the value of the count independent for each child in the list, using the child's key or index?

I was wondering trying another approach, instead of using a single number, I was thinking to use an Object and create the state depending on the clicked item, something like this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState({});

  const handleClick = (i) => {
    setCount({ ...count, [i]: 1 });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {nodeList.map((node, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              handleClick(i);
            }}
          >
            Sum up
          </button>
          <span>{count[i]}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Now, How could I get the counter on each element increased?

Comment: your code increase count only one for all elements. I think you should do like this. ``nodeList.map((node,i) => (<div key={i}><button onClick={() => setCount(prev => prev + i)}>Sum up</button><span>{count}</span></div>))``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your state is uninitiated. So `count[i]` is undefined which won't render, and `undefined + 1` returns `NaN`.

Here's a code sandbox that fixes things: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-pond-v2isz?file=/src/App.js

I used `count[i] || 0` to return `0` if count is a "falsy" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), and changed `setCount({ ...count, [i]: 1});` to `setCount({ ...count, [i]: (count[i] || 0) + 1 });`

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to create `listItem` state as an array with `useState` and update it using `index`.

[LIVE CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-clarke-qxyxf?file=/src/Counter.js)

Be sure to create a **clone array** and return from the `set` function because it won't reflect if you change in the same array.

[HOW NOT TO UPDATE AN ARRAY](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-golick-nt7jr?file=/src/Counter.js)

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Counter = () => {
  const [listItem, setListItem] = useState(Array(10).fill(0));

  function increment(index) {
    setListItem((prev) => {
      const clone = [...prev];
      clone[index] += 1;
      return clone;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {listItem.map((node, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <button onClick={() => increment(i)}>Sum up</button>
          <span>{node}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```